# How to store the contents of this CSV file into an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I'm trying to make a Java program where the contents of a CSV file of TV show data is stored in an array of TVShow objects. I made the TVShow class have a variable for each of the CSV file's categories.

When I try running, I keep getting a `NoSuchElementException`. I tried printing out the contents of the file and it worked, but I don't know what is wrong with the program.

**Edit:**
**After following advice of @gthanop, I changed the Main.java code below. The issue now is that all of the array's elements are the first row of the CSV file.**

This is the CSV file, and then my code:
[image]

```java
public class TVShow
{
  String name;
  String yearPremiered;
  String numOfSeasons;
  String numOfEpisodes;
  String network;
  String genre;
  String maleLead;
  String femaleLead;

  public TVShow(String name, String yearPremiered, String numOfSeasons, String numOfEpisodes, String network, String genre, String maleLead, String femaleLead)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.yearPremiered = yearPremiered;
    this.numOfSeasons = numOfSeasons;
    this.numOfEpisodes = numOfEpisodes;
    this.network = network;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.maleLead = maleLead;
    this.femaleLead = femaleLead;
  } 
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    TVShow[] array = new TVShow[20]; //There are 20 rows of TV show data in the CSV file

    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("tv_shows.csv"));

    read.nextLine();

    int row = 0;

    read.useDelimiter(",|\n");

    while (read.hasNext())
    {
      String name = read.next();
      String yearPremiered = read.next();
      String numOfSeasons = read.next();
      String numOfEpisodes = read.next();
      String network = read.next();
      String genre = read.next();
      String maleLead = read.next();
      String femaleLead = read.next();

      while (row < 20)
      {
        array[row] = new TVShow(name, yearPremiered, numOfSeasons, numOfEpisodes, network, genre, maleLead, femaleLead);
        row++;
      }
    }

    read.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a CSV library instead of rolling your own CSV parsing.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this is part of a homework assignment so I can't use external libraries :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `",|\n"` as the delimiter, because line separators also separate values.

For example:

```
public class Main {
    private static class TVShow {
        private final String name;
        private final int number;

        public TVShow(final String name,
                      final int number) {
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{name = " + name + ", number = " + number + '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ArrayList<TVShow> shows = new ArrayList<>();
        try (final Scanner scan = new Scanner("a,0\nb,1\nc,2")) {
            scan.useDelimiter(",|\n");
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                final String name = scan.next();
                final int number = scan.nextInt();
                shows.add(new TVShow(name, number));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(shows);
    }
}
```

**Note**: are you sure that the `read2.next()` called as the construction arguments are executed in the desired sequence? Because it happened to me once upon a time ago (I don't remember in which language though, most likely C++) that the sequence was exactly the opposite than the one intended... So make sure you read your CSV values in sequence (ie read-then-assign-to-variable) and then construct your `TVShow` object. Just like in the above example I am not calling:

```
shows.add(new TVShow(scan.next(), scan.nextInt()));
```

but instead:

```
final String name = scan.next();
final int number = scan.nextInt();
shows.add(new TVShow(name, number));
```

#### Update 1:

In your updated code, you are almost there. Just remove the inner loop like so:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    TVShow[] array = new TVShow[20]; //There are 20 rows of TV show data in the CSV file

    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("tv_shows.csv"));

    read.nextLine();

    int row = 0;

    read.useDelimiter(",|\n");

    while (read.hasNext())
    {
      String name = read.next();
      String yearPremiered = read.next();
      String numOfSeasons = read.next();
      String numOfEpisodes = read.next();
      String network = read.next();
      String genre = read.next();
      String maleLead = read.next();
      String femaleLead = read.next();

      array[row] = new TVShow(name, yearPremiered, numOfSeasons, numOfEpisodes, network, genre, maleLead, femaleLead);
      row++;
    }

    read.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

---

In my opinion though, you can expect more robust results from a library like [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv) or something similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The new delimiter helped it to compile, I applied the toString method and then tried printing the array values. So I guess the while loop only managed to fill all of the array values with the first row of the CSV :(

Comment: Basically all the array elements consist of the first TVShow object, even after I tried doing it in sequence (reading line, then assigning read.next() to each category variable, and placing them in new objects for each array element)

Comment: No problem! :) *...the while loop only managed to fill all of the array values with the first row of the CSV.* yes indeed. As for the *read-then-assign*, the whole point of it is to not read the columns of the CSV out of order, per line. As I was testing it, I found out that actually reading a single line as you did, was indeed producing the desired results (ie columns in order instead of interchanging them), but just to be safe you can *read-then-assign* for each different line, and then construct the `TVShow`.

Comment: I revised the code above for Main.java. Can you take a look? I'm not quite sure how to approach reading then assigning for each different line, before I construct the TVShow objects. Since I assumed the while loop would construct multiple objects, well one for each line

Comment: Yes the first (outter) loop will read line-by-line. Then inside the outter loop you will read all columns (just like you are doing) and create a single `TVShow` (which you are doing inside the inner loop, which is not what intended). The inner loop is not needed at all. Just directly assign the constructed `TVShow` to `array[row]` and then increment `row`. You can have a look at my **Update 1** section in this answer.